# onMouseDown/onClick event on <div> inside <div>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am new to Javascript.

There is a big `<div>` as a bar with three `<div>` inside. One of those 3 divs contains an input, which is a field the user can type things in. The input normally let the user click on it and type.

However, the default behavior of the bar is to close when the user clicks out of it, which won't let the user type because it just closes. I try to use `preventDefault()` on the big `<div>` when the mouse goes down, so that the bar won't close, and that works. But then it does not let the user type inside the input, which was possible if I don't `preventDefault()`. Can anyone explain this behavior and how to handle these events?

```
<div onMouseDown={event => {
  event.preventDefault();
}}
>
  <div className="InputBox">
    <Input placeholder="default size" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to use "stopPropagation" on the input, so the click does not propagate to the div.

```
<input onMouseDown="{event => { event.stopPropagation(); }}" placeholder... />
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. I need to prevent the event of closing the bar (therefore preventDefault()), on the big div, at the same time as letting the default event happen for the input, so I don't understand why stop the propagation at the input level.

Comment: You have to remove preventDefault on the main div

Comment: I did. But when I do that the bar just closes, so there is no time to type anything in the input. The behavior of the bar is to disappear if you click outside or type anything. I want to open this exception for the input when it is clicked.